# enter data into 2 tables with foriegn key relation based on one attribute of primary table

Tags: mysql, database, insert

I have a table 'project' that has attributes:name, UID(PK), section(distinguisher)... and 3 tables A,B,C  based on section with specific properties of each section.i want to be able to enter data into project and the section specific data into A/B/C TABLE based on entry in section attribute of project table of that row. all tables have Foreign key with UID as UID_A, UID_B, UID_C...any ideas on how i can do it? all help appreciated as i am quite a novice...thanks! I am working with Mysql workbench.

Comment: create a trigger on table 'project' and insert data depending on incoming value...

Comment: actually can you give a link or something that is easy to understand and learn on triggers??

Answer (score 0):

Well, create a trigger on the table project:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `fill_abc` AFTER INSERT ON `project`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   INSERT INTO A <some specific data...>;
   INSERT INTO B <some specific data...>;
   INSERT INTO C <some specific data...>;
END;
```

Probably, you want to handle not only inserts into this table, but updates and deletes as well - it is nearly the same idea. See [trigger definition here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) and [examples here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)